# Gradle useOldManifestMerger not found

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I've updated my gradle, and it gives me this error:

`Could not find method useOldManifestMerger() for arguments [true] on project`

I'm using android studio 1.0 RC2 with gradle plugin 1.0.0 RC2 and gradle 2.2.1.

Any idea what causes this error?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't notice the warning in the previous version that it's deprecated and will be removed from 1.0.0, so this problem is solved.

Comment: care to share your solution?

Comment: Not a helpful answer, please provide your solution :)

Comment: It is not a solution.